# Python, Угадай число

Tags: python, разработка-игр

*Я решил сделать программу которая будет сама угадывать, и сама отгадывать число.*

> Не могу решить проблему, помогите пожалуйста.

````
import random

list_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

left_number = 1
right_number = 10
simple_number = random.choice(list_number)

number = 0

while True:
    is_right = print(f'Ваше число - {simple_number}? (=, >, <)')

    if is_right < simple_number:
        print('Нет, оно больше.')
        number =+ 1

    elif is_right > simple_number:
        number =- 1

    elif is_right == simple_number:
        print('Ты угадал!')
        break

    simple_number = round((left_number + right_number) / 2)```
````

Comment: А где, собственно, вопрос?

Comment: Код выдает ошибку, как исправить?

Comment: Какую ошибку? .

Comment: if is_right < simple_number:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: `number =- 1` — а вот в этой строке вы в переменную `number` всегда записываете число -1

Comment: Функция `print` всегда возвращает `None`, поэтому значение `is_right` тоже всегда равно `None`, а `None` нельзя сравнивать с числами

Comment: Как тогда написать такую программу?

Comment: Исправить print  на input

Comment: Кажется я уже видел этот вопрос и тоже отвечал, что `print` возвращает `None`. Автор ещё раз что ли его задал? :/

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того что для получения данных нужно input а не print

```
is_right < simple_number
```

А что бы сравнивать полученные данные сначала преобразовать из строки в int

```
import random

list_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

left_number = 1
right_number = 10
simple_number = random.choice(list_number)

number = 0

while True:
    is_right = int(input(f'Ваше число - {simple_number}? (=, >, <)'))
    if is_right < simple_number:
        print('Нет, оно больше.')
        number += 1

    elif is_right > simple_number:
        number -= 1

    elif is_right == simple_number:
        print('Ты угадал!')
        break

    simple_number = round((left_number + right_number) / 2)
```

Comment: А в цикле while теперь выполняется поиск? Если нет, то зря вы весь код привели.